# Write a code to split the string “test” and assign the value of the Name to the textbox and value of ok to the Checkbox.

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

Write a code to split the string “test” and assign the value of the Name to the textbox and value of ok to the Checkbox. The check box should be checked as the value of OK is YES

In .aspx page,

Name:   (Text Box)

Ok  : (Checkbox)

In aspx.cs page,

```
       protected  void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)

       {

            String test = “Name = ADP India Pvt LTD;OK = YES “;

          }
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is simply a matter of using the [`String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method to break your existing string into two sections and then checking the values of each section :

```
// Example string
string test = "Name = ADP India Pvt LTD;OK = YES ";
// Split this into two sections (using the ';' as a delimiter)
var sections = test.Split(';');
// Now the first entry will be the name, so we need the section after
// the equals sign
Name.Text = sections[0].Split('=')[1].Trim();
// Based on the value of your "OK", determine if your checkbox should be checked
Ok.Checked = (sections[1].Split('=')[1].Trim()== "YES");
```

This isn't the safest of examples, but it should give you an idea of how you might go around solving problems like this.

If you don't mind using LINQ, you could resolve this a bit more easily by mapping your string to a Dictionary :

```
// Example string
string test = "Name = ADP India Pvt LTD;OK = YES";
// Map each key (e.g. "Name") and value (e.g. "ADP Index Pvt LTD")
// to an entry in a dictionary
var dictionary = test.Split(';')
                     .ToDictionary(k => k.Split('=')[0].Trim(), 
                                   v => v.Split('=')[1].Trim());

// Now reference what you need by it's key
Name.Text = dictionary["Name"];         // yields "ADP India Pvt LTD";
Ok.Checked = dictionary["OK"] == "YES"; // checks the checkbox if "YES"
```